# Android AlertDialog ListView w/ several TextViews and an EditText an the end

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog that has many TextViews (so that scrolling in necessary) and an EditText at the end for users to enter a value that is not included in the list.  When AlertDialog is first presented, things look good.  However, when I scroll back to the top after scrolling to the bottom problems occur.

[Here is the bottom of the list initially presented.  All good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaTBM.png)

[But here is what it looks like after I scroll to the top.  Not so good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApkrU.png)

This is the Adapter class that I am using:

```
public class MultiSelectOtherDialog extends DialogFragment {

public static final String TAG = "MultiSelectOtherDialog";

private ArrayList<Bean> mList = new ArrayList<>();

public static MultiSelectOtherDialog newInstance(String aTitle, String[] aElems) {
    MultiSelectOtherDialog frag = new MultiSelectOtherDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", aTitle);
    args.putStringArray("elems", aElems);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // length of this list determines how many items to present - need an extra for the EditText
    //  at the end for "Other"
    int mListLen = (getArguments().getStringArray("elems").length) + 1;
    //int mListLen = (getArguments().getStringArray("elems").length);
    for (int i = 0; i < mListLen; i++) {
        mList.add(new Bean());
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scb_listview2, null);

    ListView listViewItems = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvScb);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(new MultiSelectOtherAdapter());
    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListenerListViewItem());

    builder.setTitle(getArguments().getString("title")).setView(view);

    AlertDialog diagFragDialog = builder.create();

    return diagFragDialog;
}

public class MultiSelectOtherAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // needed for the "Other" EditText at the end
            if (position < mList.size() - 1) {
                convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.scb_item, null);
                holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                Log.d(TAG, "1)");
            }
            else {
                convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.scb_item_other, null);
                holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et);
                Log.d(TAG, "2)");
            }
            holder.cb = (SmoothCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scb);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            Log.d(TAG, "3)");
        }

        final Bean bean = mList.get(position);
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SmoothCheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(SmoothCheckBox checkBox, boolean isChecked) {
                bean.isChecked = isChecked;
            }
        });
        // needed for the "Other" EditText at the end
        if (position < getArguments().getStringArray("elems").length) {
            String text = getArguments().getStringArray("elems")[position];
            holder.tv.setText(text);
            Log.d(TAG, "4)");
        }
        else {
            convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.scb_item_other, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et);
            holder.cb = (SmoothCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scb);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            Log.d(TAG, "5)");
        }

        holder.cb.setChecked(bean.isChecked);
        Log.d(TAG, "6)");

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        SmoothCheckBox cb;
        TextView tv;
    }
}

public class OnItemClickListenerListViewItem implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Bean bean = (Bean) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        bean.isChecked = !bean.isChecked;
        SmoothCheckBox checkBox = (SmoothCheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.scb);
        checkBox.setChecked(bean.isChecked, true);
    }
}

class Bean implements Serializable {
    boolean isChecked;
}
```

}

And the layouts:

AlertDialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvScb"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewLineHoriz" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLineHoriz"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottonRowScb"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/bottonRowScb"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/buttonOKScb"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ok_string" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewLineVert"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancelScb"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel_string" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <cn.refactor.library.SmoothCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/scb"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And EditText item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:hint="@string/other_notes_string"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

    <cn.refactor.library.SmoothCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/scb"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter change this:

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

And, also in your getView() method, put this code:

```
converView = null;
```

before :

`if(convertView == null){
// your codes
}`

Comment: That did the trick.  This solution however negates the viewholder pattern however does it not by always setting convertView = null?  Personally I do not have a problem w/ this as the array building the list will be static at compile time and never by more than a few views beyond initially visible.